# The Present Perfect, The Present Simple, or The Future Simple? The 3 options seems ok!

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple, future-continuous

In Google's upcoming version of Chrome we read:

> There are a few conditions that must be met for media to autoplay on a
>   website. It must be muted or not have audio,
>
> > ***the user has to have tapped or clicked*** on the site while browsing, ***the site has to have been added*** to the Home Screen by
> >     the user on mobile or ***the user has to have frequently played
> >     media*** on that site if on desktop.

Why does not the writer simply use the present simple or any suitable future tense (since he speaking about the future)?

For example, in my opinion as an option, he could say:
(1)... the user has to tap or click ....
(2)..... the site has to be added ...
(3) .... the user has to frequently play media ....

I guess it is just for showing more emphasis but I am not sure.

Yet I think also that what Google will do in the future depends on what the user will be doing then OR  has done (before these modifications till the time of the modifications)
Still confuse 
Thanks

Source:
https://www.engadget.com/amp/2018/03/21/next-chrome-version-wont-autoplay-videos-with-sound/

Comment: I second you! It seems a writing style...a more complex one for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect is used to emphasize that certain conditions must be met *prior* to a video being allowed to autoplay. I have included more of the original source text to clarify.

In addition to your emphasized conditions, there is another condition in present tense (in bold below). This first condition is not in present perfect because it is something that describes the current state of the media when it tries to autoplay. The other conditions are things that must have happened in the past beforehand.

> There are a few conditions that must be met for media to autoplay on a
>   website. It **must be muted or not have audio**, ***the user has to have
>   tapped or clicked*** on the site while browsing, ***the site has to have
>   been added*** to the Home Screen by the user on mobile or ***the user has to
>   have frequently played media*** on that site if on desktop.

Your example using present tense makes it sound like a series of steps that a user would follow in order to have media autoplay on their own device. However, a website serving a video will not be able to control what actions the user may or may not have already taken by the time their video tries to autoplay.